# relative position with overflow-y scroll

Tags: jquery, css

i have this markup.

```
<ul style="position:relative; height: 150px; overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: visible">
  <li style="position: absolute; left: -300px;">text content</li>
  <li style="position: absolute; left: -300px;">text content</li>
  ...
  <li style="position: absolute; left: -300px;">text content</li>
  <li style="position: absolute; left: -300px;">
    <a href="#" id="load-more">Load more</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the markup is coming from jquery ui autocomplete, the list will slide from left to the right one by one. when i click `#load-more` what i expected is only vertical scrollbar is appear not both vertical and horizontal scrollbar. also the overflow stuff make the slide items only visible in the area of `<ul>` not outside this.

what is wrong?

Comment: `overflow-x: hidden`?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle? But seeing what you do I think query is doing a overwrite of the HTML CSS values. You can try and set the value you want using .css() method with jquery when loading more

Comment: can't create fiddle, but here is the link to the web http://comicedu.com/tubebugs/

`overflow-x: hidden` almost do that but i need the items slide from far left to the 0 position of `<ul>`